# How to hide back button from window border on Android app on Chromebook

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

On chromebooks there is back button in the window border. But this button normally shown in actionbar in android apps. I just want to hide this system button for chromebooks to avoid duplications. I see that Google Play app is managed to do it somehow.
[image: Back button in the window border]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this preference inside the activity tag

```xml
<meta-data android:name="WindowManagerPreference:SuppressWindowControlNavigationButton" android:value="true" />
```

For more information, please check out [ChromeOS.dev](https://chromeos.dev/en/android/optimizing#change-navigation-patterns) and their help article on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, will try it and accept if it works. I have read all docs on https://developer.android.com/chrome-os and found no mention about it

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul - Just checking in. Did this work for you?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you! ChromeOS.dev is the new resource for all things related to Chrome OS development, so this may be a good resource for you moving forwad